# Uncaught ReferenceError: async is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, smartcontracts, web3js, moralis

How to define `async`? I try to declare `async = require('async')` and no success. Then I try on terminal: `npm install async --save` and same thing without result.

```js
async function donate() {

  let options = {
    contractAddress: "0x..",
    functionName: "newDonation",
    abi: [{ ....
    }],
    params: {
      note: "Thanks from Mr. Popcorn!"
    },
    msgValue: Moralis.Units.ETH(0.2)
  }
  await Moralis.executionFunction(options);
}


async function login() {
  let user = Moralis.User.current()

  if (!user) {
    try {
      user = await Moralis.authenticate({
        signingMessage: `
                Authenticate to popcorn!
                
                Please make sure to understand the terms.
    
                `
      })
      await Moralis.enableWeb3()
      console.log(user.get('ethAddress'))

      document.getElementById("popcorn").innerHTML = `
                <p>Wallet: ${user.get('ethAddress')}</p>
                <p><button id="donate_btn" onclick=${donate}>Donate</button></p>            
                `;

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}

async function logOut() {
  await Moralis.User.logOut()
  console.log("Logged out!")
}

document.getElementById("login_btn").onclick = login;
document.getElementById("logout_btn").onclick = logOut;
```

Comment: Is this code nodejs or vanilla javascript on the browser?

Comment: I use node.js for this application

Answer (score -1):

try this and let me know if its work.

```
document.getElementById("login_btn").onclick = function(){
  return login()
}
document.getElementById("logout_btn").onclick = function(){
  return logOut()
}
```

Comment: Thanks so lot for your tips, but It still does not work. I try with var async = require('async'); and var _ = require('lodash');   ....but same thing.... and finaly, I try npm install async --save.